# Ext-js4 MVC tabspanel onclose event

Tags: tabs, event-handling, extjs4

I need to implement global onclose event on a tab panel component, so whenever a tab is being closed, I want something to happen.

Can this be accomplished ?

Answer (score 1):

Using MVC controllers it very easy to listen to such events. Here is a sample code that goes into an instance of an Ext.app.Controller class :

```
init:function () {
    this.control(
       'tabpanel tab':{
            close:this.onTabClose
        } 
        .....
}
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/UqfFH/